# golang websocket data is not right

Tags: go, websocket

I'm using `x.net.websocket` to read data from a websocket. 
The data is relatively large. When I read it, I can't read it completely, so it is cut off.
Is there any way to solve it?

```
func receiveWebsocket(ws *websocket.Conn) error {
    for {
        var msg = make([]byte, 1024*1024) // 1024kb
        m, err := ws.Read(msg) 
        if err != nil {
            log15.Error("ws read error", "error", err)
            return err
        }
        fmt.Println("length ---",m,  string(msg))
        response := string(msg[:m])
        assignmentWebsocket(response)
    }
}
```

According to the log, the `m` value is always 4092, even if `msg` is very large.

Comment: i used this method

Comment: example: https://gist.github.com/bingqianglin/7c7af34eb53f68efab5457dd7d631f4b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call always reads less than 4KB, and for security reasons the length is limited, if you want to increase, set:

```
ws.MaxPayloadBytes = xxxx
```

From the second call your msg will be filled.

If you want to read the whole message in a single call,do:

```
msg, err := ioutil.ReadAll(ws)
```

Comment: i found this  setting is not working , at last ,i use this lib `github.com/gorilla/websocket`, it worked now.